# How can I use tensorflow-transform to handle images for example define an opereation to reduce the mean of the images

Tags: python, tensorflow-transform

How can I use tensorflow-transform to reduce the mean value of images and in order that it will work also during serving

Comment: By "reducing the mean value of images", do you mean converting the images from Color to Grey Scale? If it is not, what exactly do you mean

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to reduce the Mean Value of Images, i.e., you want to convert Images from Color to Grey Scale (which divides the values of the Pixels by 255, and hence their Mean will be reduced)

We can define that as a Tensorflow Operation, `tf.divide(outputs[key], 255)` inside the `preprocessing_fn` of the `Tensorflow Transform`, so that these changes can be applied during Training as well as in Serving. You can try Tensorflow 2.0 Alpha so that there won't be any need of creating a session.

```
def preprocessing_fn(inputs):
  """Preprocess input columns into transformed columns."""
  # Since we are modifying some features and leaving others unchanged, we
  # start by setting `outputs` to a copy of `inputs.
  outputs = inputs.copy()

  # Convert the Image from Color to Grey Scale. 
  # NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS is the names of Columns of Values of Pixels
  for key in NUMERIC_FEATURE_KEYS:
    outputs[key] = tf.divide(outputs[key], 255)

  outputs[LABEL_KEY] = outputs[LABEL_KEY]

  return outputs
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: RakTheGeek, I'm trying to convert a byte string for an array to a 2d array in `preprocessing_fn`. It seems like it would work based upon the `preprocessing_fn`'s output, but `tf.Transform` later shows a byte string still. Would you have any idea about this? Here's the Github issue I created: https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/issues/119#issuecomment-491605786